# Centering content in tables

Tags: formatting

Hi guys I am new to LaTeX, I have a very large table with data in it which moves past the page. I have managed to fix it and adjust it according to the page but I lost the centering option for the data can you please tell me how to center the data while maintaining the specification I have provided for the length the columns I have attached the code I am using so you can understand me better

`\begin{tabular}{ | p{5cm} | p{2cm} | p{2cm} | p{2cm} |}`

I tried adding `c` to the code like `| c p{5cm} |` but it still wouldn't center the data inserted in the table. Thank you

Comment: You can repeat columns with `*{3}{p{2cm}|}`, small tip ;-)

Answer (score 1):

(1) Always post minimal examples that can be copied and compiled as is. This is a sniplet. MWEs makes it a lot easier to help

```
\usepackage{array}

 \begin{tabular}{ | 
  >{\centering\arraybackslash} p{5cm} 
   | >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm} 
   | >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm} 
   | >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{2cm} |}
```

`array` enables up to get the `>{...}` construction, so we insert `\centering` into each cell. But this messes with `\\` so it nolonger means **new row**, `\arraybackslash` brings back the original table definition

And do consider if those lines are really necessary (they often make the tale much less readable)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `array` package and define a new column type `C` which uses the `p` type and centers it.

It would be possible to write this directly in the `tabular` column definition, but the `\newcolumntype` is cleaner, especially if there are more than on columns to change.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|C{5cm}|*{3}{C{2cm}|}}
\hline
a & b & c & d \tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: When you have the `\arraybackslash` is there then any reason to use `\tabularnewline?`

Comment: @daleif: No, my coding genes just force me to write `\tabularnewline` ;-)

Comment: thank you so much guys ... issue resolved I will be soon posting a really complex table i made in word that i want to put in LaTeX... first one to solve it gets a cookie... let the games begin xD